# How to load historic data with PayPal TransactionSearch API

Tags: paypal

I am using C# and the Paypal SOAP API with the TransactionSearch method. I am trying to get all historic items from our account:

```
        var client = new PayPalAPIInterfaceClient();

        var credentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType
        {
            Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType
            {
                Username = PaypalUsername,
                Password = PaypalPassword,
                Signature = PaypalSignature
            }
        };
        var request = new TransactionSearchReq
        {
            TransactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType
            {
                StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1),
                Status = PaymentTransactionStatusCodeType.Success,
                Version = "95.0"
            }
        };

        var response = client.TransactionSearch(ref credentials, request);
```

This just gives me Transactions that are at most 30 days old, whatever I put in there as start date. The API documentation says, that this method starts looking from the start date and returns the (at most) 100 transactions after this point. I can't achieve this here though. Is this a known problem? Does anyone use this API here with success?

When querying old transaction through the GetTransactionDetails method, I get the data, so it is not as if they are not available. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever sorted this, but I believe you have your date in the wrong format.

I believe `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)` outputs `09/21/2012 19:01:36`, whereas the docs state;

> The value must be in UTC/GMT format; for example, 2012-09-21T19:01:36Z

Comment: I never made this work, no. As for the date: The C# client library from PayPal expects a DateTime object here. I don't think that it is converted to a string directly and rather hope, that they do it properly inside the library, but of course no one knowns in the end. I probably would need to look at the traffic and the disassembled code to find out.